# Abstract method Exception on ServletContextListener

Tags: java, servlets, gwt

I'm relatively new to Java, and am finding the exceptions it throws to be frustratingly obtuse. I have been trying to have a "main" thread in a Servlet based program based around GWT, and found many suggestions online to use `ServletContextListener` to go about this.

I am not yet trying to do anything with this context listener, just get the framework in place to start writing my main routine. The entirety of my `ServletContextListener` implementation right now looks like this:

```
package com.myPackage.server;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class mainProcess implements ServletContextListener {

public void contextInitalized(ServletContextEvent evt){
    System.out.println("**************** Context Inialized Called ****************");
    }

public void contextDestoryed(ServletContextEvent evt){
    System.out.println("**************** Servlet Context Destoryed ****************");
    }
}
```

Running this program as I have showed it above throws no errors specifically, but it also doesn't ever print out the lines.

I am using Jersey-2.2 which I believe implements Servlet version > 3.0 (brand new project with the latest everything) so (from my understanding) I shouldn't have to implement the interface in my web.xml file.

However for grins, if I try adding the `<listener>` to my web.xml file:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.myPackage.server.mainProcess</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I suddenly get a huge error block starting with:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)

This seems like too simple a implementation to be throwing errors when no logic code has even been added to the context handler! And so far the Java errors are so unhelpful to me (I do a lot of C development and find the compiler errors thrown by GCC to be far more helpful in debugging what actually happened!)

Where do I even start looking for the solution to this? Seeing the AbstractMethodError made me start to think that I needed to @Override the default methods of the ServletContextListener class, but that threw its own set of errors claiming that I was not overriding the methods of the superclass. But I have seen that exact code block in multiple places online. So something is wonky, and after googling around quite a bit I'm not 100% certain where to even start looking here.

Comment: Wait, adding `@Override` says that? So you have something wrong with dependencies, try to remove those methods and line with your class declaration should be underlined if you are using IDE, then click 'add unimplemented methods' or something like that and see what happens.

Comment: OK, so that actually just worked! Didn't solve the "its not running the function" bit, but suddenly the @Override is not complaining anymore & the function is highlighted and no longer saying its unused. That seems like it must just be a IDE thing. I'm currently using Intellij 2016.2.4 (latest version).. Not sure why that would have caused a problem....

Comment: Nevermind, that actually DID solve the problem. I can now include the <listener> function into my web.xml file and it runs the ServletContextListener process without throwing the abstract method error. The real question here becomes, why do I have to include it in my web.xml file? Since I'm using @WebLIstener shouldn't that handle it without need to include that extra XML reference?